# Modifying values of terminals on run-time in ANTLR

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr

Suppose I have a simple grammar that looks like this:

```
name -> girl_name | boy_name;
girl_name -> 'Matilda' | 'Vicky' | 'Alice';
boy_name -> 'Spike' | 'Athos' | 'Mike';
```

and am modelling it in ANTLRv3. Is it possible, that at run-time, I augument the set of values that the boy_name and girl_name terminals can take?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your lexer grammar, you could include a very simple definition for `NAME`.

```
NAME : ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+;
```

Then define `GIRL_NAME` and `BOY_NAME` tokens by creating `fragment` rules.

```
fragment GIRL_NAME : ;
fragment BOY_NAME : ;
```

Then, create code to assign a `NAME` to either `GIRL_NAME` or `BOY_NAME`.

```
@members {
    public static final Set<String> GIRL_NAMES = new HashSet<String>();
    static {
        GIRL_NAMES.add("Matilda");
        GIRL_NAMES.add("Vicky");
        GIRL_NAMES.add("Alice");
    }

    public static final Set<String> BOY_NAMES = new HashSet<String>();
    static {
        BOY_NAMES.add("Spike");
        BOY_NAMES.add("Athos");
        BOY_NAMES.add("Mike");
    }

    public static final int ClassifyName(String name) {
        if (GIRL_NAMES.contains(name)) {
            return GIRL_NAME;
        } else if (BOY_NAMES.contains(name)) {
            return BOY_NAME;
        } else {
            return NAME;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then modify your `NAME` rule with an embedded action to assign the proper type.

```
NAME
    :   ('A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z')+
        {$type = ClassifyName($text);}
    ;
```

Comment: Does this method work for a more complex grammar? In other words, is it possible to return terminals like this and in effect match entire non terminals? A - > B {$type = ClassifyName($text)} C {$type = ClassifyName($text)}.